# What is the choice way to temporarily animate a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm writing some custom controller transitions, and wish to avoid using something like Hero in order to maintain control of my UINavigationController's `delegate` property. On the question of *how* to actually animate the views, I'm at a bit of a crossroads.

To be clear, this isn't a "move each controller's entire view in one animation" transition, such as a simple cross-fade. Rather, I want to make individual subviews of each transitioning view move and fade in a cascading pattern. The animations must be interactive. The subviews make use of autolayout, and I wish to avoid keeping track of dozens of constraints.

So far, I have found that modifying a view's `transform` property allows you to modify position, scale, and rotation without disturbing constraints. Of equal importance, you can remove the modifications by restoring an identity transformation. It is supported by `UIViewPropertyAnimator`.

Modifying a view's transform property seems to be pretty uncommon so it seems like a good route for doing transitions. The other idea I had was to create a *copy* of each transitioning view, and modify the properties of that, but I don't see much advantage in doing so, other than preserving the ability to have a non-identity transform.

What is the common practice for this? What patterns do develops typically follow?

Comment: I have found that snapshotting the views add to view in same frame and hiding all the real ones is the best for me. Aside from that you can animate however you want. I use all of the above CAAnimations,UIView, and sometimes Facebook Pop